# How to send data from Greasemonkey to a PHP (WAMP) server?

Tags: php, wamp, greasemonkey

I am creating a Greasemonkey script where I am calculating six variables (time, move, scroll, sav, prin, book and url).

I need to send these variables' data to my PHP page so that these could be inserted in a MySQL table using a WAMP server.

Please, can anyone give the exact code to it as I am new to all this?

My Greasemonkey script is:

```
{var ajaxDataObj = {
    s:      sav,
    p:      prin,
    b:      book,
    t:      finalTime,
    u:      url,
    a:      totalScroll,
    b:      tot
};

var serializedData  = JSON.stringify (ajaxDataObj);

GM_xmlhttpRequest ( {
    method: "POST",
    url:    "localhost/anuja/greasemonkey.php",
    data:   serializedData,
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0",    // If not specified, navigator.userAgent will be used.
        "Accept": "text/xml"            // If not specified, browser defaults will be used.
} }
```

and php side is:

```
$jsonData   = json_decode($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA);

echo jsonData.u;
```

this code is not running.. Plus I try to check if my variable `u` has been passed using `jsonData.u`, but it just echoes "jsonData.u".

Comment: Why do you implement that in greasemonkey, and not in normal javascipt (which you put on your wamp server) instead?

Comment: @Wimmel, that would be because the GM script is running on a page he does not serve/control.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9401009/greasemonkey-ajax-request-is-not-sending-data

Comment: see i am studying user's behaviour for different pages,for which i am using greasemonkey.. now i need to store those data somewhere wgich is mysql in this case... so i need it for that... can anyone please help me with the exact code

Comment: @user2039532 did you see the link Brock has posted. His answer contains all you need.

Comment: That code has some syntax errors and `GM_xmlhttpRequest` is missing callbacks.  See the error console (Control + Shift + J) for help with that. The PHP file should use `echo $jsonData.u;` or even `print_r ($jsonData);`.

Comment: y is it showing u undefined???

Answer (score -1):

I just create userscript to make Greasemonkey scrape data from webpage opened and POST parameters to the PHP script hosted on my local XAMPP server which could run local Python scripts to automate works.

This also a cool method for scrping data from Javascript rendered pages, which is hard for Python scraper, even better than Selenium :P

The parameters are seperated by `&` in this PHP sample url:

```
http://www.sciencedirect.com/search?qs=Vascular%20stent&authors=&pub=&volume=&issue=&page=&origin=home&zone=qSearch&offset=1200
```

GM script part:

```
// @grant        GM_xmlhttpRequest
unsafeWindow.sendPhp2Py = function(){
    //var ytitle = 'Youtube - ' + document.querySelector('div.yt-user-info').textContent.trim();
    var yurl = document.location.href;
    //console.info(ytitle);
    //console.info(yurl);
    var ret = GM_xmlhttpRequest({
        method: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost/php_run_py.php",
        //data: "ytitle="+ ytitle + "&yurl="+ yurl,
        data: "yurl="+ yurl,
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        },
        onload: function(response) {
            console.log(response);
            // readyState 4 = complete
            // status = 200 OK
            if(response.readyState == 4 && response.status == 200){
                document.querySelector('#myPhpPyBtn').textContent = 'Sent to PHP!';
            }
        },
        onerror: function(e){
            console.log(e);
            document.querySelector('#myPhpPyBtn').textContent = 'PHP not connected';
        }
    });
};
```

PHP scipt:

```
<?php
    echo $_POST['yurl'];
//传递多个参数如下可以行得通 参数里包含空格哦也可以！！赞 Multiple parameters pass
    //echo shell_exec("python test.py \"".$_POST['ytitle']."\" \"".$_POST['yurl']."\"");
    //echo shell_exec("python GreaseMonkey_Php_Youtube_srt_generator.py ".$_POST['yurl']);
//更安全 Safer
    //system(escapeshellcmd("python test.py \"".$_POST['ytitle']."\" \"".$_POST['yurl']."\""));
    system(escapeshellcmd("python GreaseMonkey_Php_Youtube_srt_generator.py ".$_POST['yurl']));
?>
```

Python test script:

```
#coding=utf-8
import sys
f = open("test.txt", "a+")
f.write(sys.argv[1] + "\n" + sys.argv[2]+ "\n") 
f.close()
print ("some output")
```

Hope it can help!